# ZFS cannot delete directory tree

Tags: zfs

Debian 9 (stretch) with ZFS 0.7.12 on kernel 4.15.18-9-pve. I have a ZFS pool with a dataset:

```
zfs list
NAME                       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                     2.81T  39.3T   120K  /rpool
rpool/data                2.81T  39.3T    96K  /rpool/data
rpool/data/vm-101-disk-0  7.74G  39.3T  7.74G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-0  5.62G  39.3T  5.62G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1  2.82T  39.3T  2.82T  -

mount -t zfs
/rpool on /rpool type zfs (rw,xattr,noacl)
/rpool/data on /rpool/data type zfs (rw,xattr,noacl)
```

For a short while I had a dataset at `rpool/store`, too, with some files and directories stored in `/rpool/store` but I used `zfs destroy rpool/store` to remove it.

I now find I have a copy of the directory structure still at `/rpool/store`:

```
ls /rpool/store/
dump  images  private  template
```

I tried to remove them but to no avail:

```
rm -rf /rpool/store
ls /rpool/store/
dump  images  private  template
```

If I ignore this situation and try to recreate my `store` dataset I get this error:

```
zfs create rpool/store
cannot mount '/rpool/store': directory is not empty
filesystem successfully created, but not mounted
```

How do I remove the files and directories at `/rpool/store`?

Comment: Do attempts to rename the `store` directory fail as well?

Comment: does `rm -rf /rpool/store` emit any error messages?

Comment: without the `-f` maybe, to have a chance to read the error?

Comment: Well that was interesting. `cd /rpool; ls` gives `data store` as described. `mv store junk; rm -rf junk` deletes the problem directory. **Thank you all three of you.** Who wants the points, or should I write up my own answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was interesting. Working from the suggestions in the comments, this deleted the problem directory where a straightforward `rm -rf store` generated no error message but would not delete:

```
cd /rpool
mv store junk
rm -rf junk
```

I have no idea why this should have worked when the other did not.